# Django Invalid credentials: User object check_password returns True, but authenticate function returns False

Tags: python, django, authentication

I've a user account in Django's default User model, where the account's `check_password()` is True, but the `authenticate` function doesn't return user the object with the same password, and it is happening only for this user.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='user_1')
>>> user.check_password('1234')
// returns True
>>> authenticate(username='user_1', password='1234')
// returns False
```

and most importantly it happens only to this user object [username: user_1] and not to any other users.

I've tried resetting the password using set_password()

```
>>> user.set_password('1234')
>>> user.save()
```

Even after resetting the password, the authenticate still doesn't returns the user object and it resets for other users properlly.

The question is, why it is happening for a specific user and not for any other users.

Django version: 2.2

Comment: Does the user have the `is_active` flag set to `False`?

Comment: Hey @IainShelvington, I just found out that the `is_active` set to `False`, noob mistake. Thanks