# Why is Django check_password=True but authenticate=None

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to write a unit test for a login endpoint in Django using as much of the built in functionality as possible.

There are existing tests that confirm that the account create endpoint is functioning properly.

In the login view, however, the `check_password()` function will return `True` for this test, but the `authenticate()` function returns `None`.

Is it safe to use the `check_password()` function instead?

Otherwise, how do I update this code to use the `authenticate()` function?

`accounts.py`

```
class Account(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, null=False, default='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'password']

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'accounts'
        db_table = 'accounts_account'

    objects = models.Manager()
```

`test_login.py`

```
def test_login(self):
    # Create account
    request_create = self.factory.post('/accounts/account',
                                       self.request_data,
                                       content_type='application/json')
    view = AccountView.as_view()
    response_create = view(request_create)

    # Login account
    request_login = self.factory.post('/accounts/login',
                                      self.request_data,
                                      content_type='application/json')

    view = LoginView.as_view()
    response = view(request_login)
```

`views.py`

```
class LoginView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        r = json.loads(request.body)
        username = r.get('username')
        password = r.get('password')
        cp = check_password(password, Account.objects.get(username=username).password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

P.S. I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70998720/django-invalid-credentials-user-object-check-password-returns-true-but-authent) thread and `is_active` is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe. The main difference is that by using [check_password()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers) you are manually checking an User from an authentication backend, thus you have to retrieve the user object and compare its password with the plain text like you do at:

```
check_password(password, Account.objects.get(username=username).password)
```

While, with [authenticate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users) it is possible to check credentials against several authentication backends. Meaning that with the former you couldn't hook your application with [other authentication sources](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#other-authentication-sources)

You are missing some code in `tests.py` and `views.py`. That being said, here is a full test of this `LoginView`:

tests.py

```
class TestClientLogin(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='test_user',
            email='test_user@example.com',
            password='super_secret'
        )

    
    def test_user_login(self):
        request_data = {'username': 'test_user', 'password': 'super_secret'}
        request = self.factory.post(
            '/accounts/login/', 
            request_data , 
            content_type='application/json'
        )

        response = LoginView.as_view()(request)
        data = json.loads(response.content)

        self.assertEqual(self.user.username, data['username'])
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

views.py

```
class LoginView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        username = data.get('username')
        password = data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            return JsonResponse({'username': user.username})
        else:
             return JsonResponse({'username': None})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use as much of the **built in functionality** as possible:

## settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'
```

## accounts/models.py:

```
class Account(AbstractUser):
    # you dont need to define username or password again
    ...

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'password']

    class Meta:
        # you don't need to define default app_label, db_table

     objects = UserManager()  # otherwise don't work "python manage.py createsuperuser"
```

## accounts/views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView


class ClientLogin(LoginView):
    pass
```

## accounts/tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

class TestClientLogin(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        self.username, self.password = get_random_string(20), get_random_string(20)  # don't use constants in tests
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username=self.username, password=self.password )

    def test_user_login(self):
        request_data = {'username': self.username, 'password': self.password}
        response = Client().post('/accounts/login/', request_data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

## BUT:

**you don't need to test `ClientLogin`, you don't have any code in view.**